# Attach multiple files in Gmail fails to send - ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, parcelable

I need to attach multiple files in mail. The count increases as per user entry. The minimum attachment count is 2. When I try attaching 2 files and send using `new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE)`, it sends and receives perfectly without any issues. If I attach more or equal 4 files, it shows in attachment before sending. But fails to receive. Also if I look into the sent items, attachment was missing.

```
final Intent ei = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
ei.setType("plain/text");
ei.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] {"xyz@gmail.com"});
ei.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, " Data Export");

ei.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uris);
context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(ei, " Data Export"));
```

The attachment size is minimal. Generally it will be .csv files.

Comment: your Attachment size should less then 15Mb .. And If You Are Sending Multiple File then Why Don't you Zip All File And Send Single Attachment ?

Comment: I will try with zip files. But my each file size will be around 1 - 10 kb only.

Comment: try this (android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE) instead  Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE and setType("message/rfc822");